# Is this sentence grammatically valid. "It's been decades and centuries that people are hoarding money?"

Tags: grammar

I'm confused between "it's been decades and centuries that people are hoarding money" and "it's been decades and centuries since people have been hoarding money." Which one is correct?

Comment: They mean opposite things, and they're both okay.

Comment: Your use of  "decades and centuries" seems strange. If it's been centuries then the decades aren't going to matter much. Depending on your exact definition of 'money', people have actually been hoarding money for millennia.

Comment: Both strike me as very odd, as the timeframe of decades is entirely subsumed by centuries, so it's rather unnecessary - the meaning would be entirely unchanged by omitting it. You wouldn't say you've lived somewhere for "days and years", as days don't make any difference if you aren't even bothering to specify how many years.

Comment: I think they’re both wrong. People have been hoarding ... for centuries.

Comment: If you want the time period to come first, then say: *For centuries, people have been hoarding money*. *It's been centuries since* means that people have stopped hoarding money, and we don't use *it's been centuries that ...* [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It%27s+been+years+that%3Aeng_us_2019%2CIt%27s+been+years+since%3Aeng_us_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIt%20%27s%20been%20years%20that%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIt%20%27s%20been%20years%20since%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0).